# Clarifying a factually incorrect case but editor opts for formatting change instead?

Tags: discussion, support, editing, answers, suggested-edits

I am trying to edit [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243533/how-to-intuitively-understand-eigenvalue-and-eigenvector/243553#243553), which makes a claim about eigenvectors that is not true for all matrices. [My edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1346119) was rejected. Instead, the editor followed up with a baffling [formatting edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/243553/revisions) that does nothing to address the over-claiming statement in the answer. While I understand my edit is not perfect, it at least makes the answer less wrong.

Surely, it is better to at least give people knowledge of a caveat, rather than let them incorrectly believe an overgeneralization?

Comment: By the way, if anyone is interested in my specific evidence for the edit I am making, here is a counterexample: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437569/do-eigenvectors-correspond-to-direction-of-maximum-scaling#comment7397070_1437569

Comment: Could you clarify what specifically you want to discuss or ask support about? The question in the post seems rhetorical. Waiting for further clarification, I'll remark that a better edit summary might have helped.  For example you could have referenced the old comment that already makes the clarification you attempted to include in the post. On the mathematics the nature of the "only" would also better be clarified. I did not think this through in all details but I assume the claim is also true for normal matrices that are not symmetric.

Comment: One might also think that lifting a snippet of information from a comment is not a  worthwhile suggested edit to an old post. But on that  certainly different opinions can be held.

Comment: I agree that that formatting edit is baffling!